# Question on series being expressed in closed form

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, closed-form

Given an integer $k$ and $0\leq \alpha \leq 1$, let $f_1(\alpha)=1/k$ and $f_{i+1}(\alpha)=\frac{(k-1)f_i(\alpha) + (f_i(\alpha)^{1/\alpha} + 1)^\alpha}{k}$.

Consider the function $g(\alpha) = \lim_{k\rightarrow +\infty} f_k(\alpha)$. It can be easily verified that $g(1) = 1$, which follows since $f_k(1) = 1$. Similarly, $g(0) = 1-1/e$, which is shown by the fact that $f_k(0) = 1-(1-1/k)^k$.

My question is: can $g(\alpha)$ be expressed in a closed form in terms of $\alpha$?

Following is a plot of $g(\alpha)$ using MATLAB simulation. 
[image]

Comment: You seem to be using superscripts both for parameters and for exponents. This is somewhat confusing. Can you find a better notation? Ditto for $k$, which is used both as a parameter and as an index.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I just fixed the notation. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: So $f_k(\alpha)$ is what you get by using the formulas you give and stopping at the $k$th "iterate"?

Comment: You're right. For any $k$ and $\alpha$, there is such a sequence of length $k$: $\{f_1(\alpha),...,f_k(\alpha)\}$.